# locking some special rows of a database table n django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a model in Django like follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    STATUS_DEFAULT = "default"
    STATUS_ACCEPTED = "accepted"
    STATUS_REJECTED = "rejected"
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_DEFAULT, 'Just Asked'),
        (STATUS_ACCEPTED, 'Accepted'),
        (STATUS_REJECTED, 'Rejected'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=20, default=STATUS_DEFAULT)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

Notice that `Question` is another model in my project. I have a constraint on the `A` model. Between rows with the same question only one of them can has `status=STATUS_ACCEPTED` and at the first all of them have `status=STATUS_DEFAULT`. I want to write a function that does the following :

```
def accept(self):
    self.status = STATUS_ACCEPTED
    self.save()
    A.objects.filter(question=self.question).update(status=STATUS_REJECTED)
```

But if two instances of `A` with same question call this function maybe a race condition will happen. So the one who calls this function sooner should lock other instances with same question to prevent race condition.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a DB backend that supports locks, you can lock the question using [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)

You code could then look like:

```
@transaction.atomic
def accept(self):
    # Lock related question so no other instance will run the following code at the same time.
    Question.objects.filter(pk=self.question.pk).select_for_update()

    # now we have the lock, reload to make sure we have not been updated meanwhile
    self.refresh_from_db()
    if self.status != STATUS_REJECTED:
        A.objects.filter(question=self.question).exclude(pk=self.pk).update()
        self.status = STATUS_ACCEPTED
        self.save()
    else:
        raise Exception('An answer has already been accepted !')
```

With that code, only one instance at a time will be able to run the code after `select_for_update` (for a given question).

Note the `refresh_from_db` call as while waiting to acquire the lock, another instance may have accepted another answer...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to make sure that two instances of `A` which share a Question cannot both simultaneously have the `'accepted'` status. `A` objects are initiated at the `default` status.

Perhaps you should rethink your approach:

Let the question itself tell you which `A` has the `accepted` status.

### Solution:

add the following to your Question model:

```
accepted_a = models.OneToOneField(A, null = true, default = null)
```

since you seem to want the accept method to be part of the `A` class, you can write your accept the way you have it laid out in your question. I disagree though, I think the behaviour of the `Question` is that the `Question` accepts the A, so the method should be defined in `Question` class.

```
def accept(self,A):
  self.accepted_a = A
```

now, in your views, when you want the `A` to get accepted, you would write:

```
q = Question.objects.get(Question_id)
a = A.objects.get(A_id)
q.accept(A)
q.save()
```

### How this works:

Django (and databases in general) provides a mechanism by which a relationship can specify One-to-One relationships. By using that in the `Question` model, we specify that each question can have *exactly* one accepted `A`. This does not override or alter the behaviour of the Many-to-One relationship the `Question` has with `A`.

Our accept is a bit naive though, it doesn't look to see if the question is a foreign key to `A`. We chan change that (or any other logic you wish):
Edit: With information provided in comments, we need to ensure that the first `Ask` (`A`) To accept the question locks it out.  To that end, we will check if the question already has an acceptor Ask. Since a question defaults to `null`, we can simply test if it is null.

```
def accept(self, A):
  if (A.question == self) and (self.accepted_a==null):
    self.accepted_a = A
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: What if two A objects call the function on their question? which one is saved as accepted?

Comment: the way I've got it set up, the *question* calls the the function. (Or rather, the method is a method of a Question). You can change the accepted answer, but you can't have more than one. So the last time `q.accept(A)` is called will be the A that is the accepted A.

Comment: I got you answer. My senario is this. I have a "Question" object and lots of "Ask" objects related to this question. Each "Ask" is asked from one person. Each person should accept the question to answer it and I want only one person can accept it. So the function is called once for each "Ask" and maybe many times with each "Question"

Comment: I want if two persons accepts the question at the same time, prevent race condition.

Comment: Okay. I've edited my solution a bit, it will now prevent a second `A` (Ask?) from accepting the question if the question already has one. You should specify behaviour if `A` is deleted, and also you should probably try to be more specific with your model names. The amount of code you save by not typing "Ask" will be outweighed by the extra effort involved in decoding your code later.

Comment: Also, this has it such that one ask can only accept one question at a time. If that is not the intended behaviour, use a ForeignKey field.

Comment: Sorry Owen, in you new solution race condition is possible. I should use some sort of lock

Comment: What race condition? Resolving race conditions simply means specifying behaviour in the event of simultaneous access. We've done that. Can you show me how you're testing this?

Comment: suppose A1 has reached the if line and is passed and after that control is passed to A2 and also it is on the if line and it also passes the if line. After that race condition happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147575/discussion-between-mohammad-and-owen-hempel).